# Null value when trying to mock a byte[] value in with junit5 and mockito

Tags: java, null, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to mock a `byte` but in the method this value is `null`. I'm using the `eq()` method to send the `byte[]` that I need to test this method.

This is the signature of my method:

```
      @Override
      public void addFile(String directory, String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
        try (SftpSession session = sessionFactory.getSession()) {
          makeSureDirectoryIsAvailable(session, directory);

          InputStream fileByteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
          session.write(fileByteStream, directory + "/" + fileName);
        }
      }
```

When I take a look to the content variable it is `null` and the strings are empty, I am not pretty sure how can I mock this value, the next is the code of my test, I'm using JUnit 5.

```
package service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoSettings;
import org.mockito.quality.Strictness;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class SFTPServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    SftpSession sftpSession;
    @Mock
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SFTPServiceImpl sftpServiceImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        sftpServiceImpl = new SFTPServiceImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    void addFile() throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = {69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, (byte) 196, (byte) 195, 61, 101, 98};

        given(sessionFactory.getSession()).willReturn(sftpSession);
        given(sftpSession.exists(anyString())).willReturn(false);

        sftpServiceImpl.addFile(anyString(), anyString(),eq(bytes));
    }

    @Test
    void getFileContent() {
    }

    @Test
    void deleteFile() {
    }

    @Test
    void moveFile() {
    }

    @Test
    void listFiles() {
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to test `sftpServiceImpl.addFile()`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to test sftpServiceImpl.addFile()

Comment: Instead of replying to the comment, i thought i will just expand and write an answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to test `sftpServiceImpl.addFile()`, you are doing it wrong. You should not pass `anyString()` and `eq(bytes)` to the method you are testing.

Instead, I will suggest to use `ArgumentCaptor` and see the `session.write()` is being called with correct parameters (which you are actually passing to  `sftpServiceImpl.addFile()`)

The code will look something like this -

```
@Mock
SftpSession sftpSession;

@Mock
DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<InputStream> captor;

private SFTPServiceImpl sftpServiceImpl;

@BeforeEach
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sftpServiceImpl = new SFTPServiceImpl(sessionFactory);
}

@Test
void addFile() throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = {69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, (byte) 196, (byte) 195, 61, 101, 98};

    given(sessionFactory.getSession()).willReturn(sftpSession);
    given(sftpSession.exists(anyString())).willReturn(false);

    String directory = "testDirectory";
    String fileName = "testFileName";

    sftpServiceImpl.addFile(directory, fileName, bytes);

    verify(sftpSession, times(1)).write(captor.capture(), eq(directory + "/" + fileName));

    // you need to compare the byte arrays here
    assertArrayEquals(bytes, captor.getValue());
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, but my doubt is about the session variable from where did you get it and it seems like assertArrayEquals didn't accept this parameters. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer, it was called `sftpSession` in the test. Yes, you can use any method you want to compare the arrays :). I just wrote this answer on the stackoverflow answer section and did not use any actual IDE :)